# Simple orthogonal graph edge routing algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph

Many graphing applications use orthogonal edge routing for "objects" on a canvas.

I am aware of the brilliant collection of algorithms found in the open source project titled QuickGraph (http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) but the layout is left to actual layout renderers (such as GraphViz (http://www.graphviz.org) and MSAGL (found on Microsoft store))

Is there a simple algorithm that takes into account the bounds of each object and the anchor points of the end and start points of an edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the algorithm, but I know orthogonal routing (node link rendering, right?) is also called "Manhattan" layout, you may find something more about it under that name.

Comment: I investigated this Manhattan and thank you. This algorithm really does look appealing and close to what I can utilize.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a layout algorithm and not a routing algorithm.  If you're really looking for a routing algorithm, then something like [Open Shortest Path First](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FOpen_Shortest_Path_First&ei=GqJXSqCBGsSfjAf8mYHiAg&usg=AFQjCNG5umbgBoCl6nyT_gEL2KvX-WNgPQ&sig2=zatf-7bftOc5I_vqBwvJ_A) is a simple one to implement.

Comment: Yes, layout is precise. Although, layout would usually refer to the "nodes" themselves and that's not what I am looking for, rather the layout of the edges between the "nodes" using an orthogonal layout.